# How do I solve 'DATE_TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DBO.DATE_TRUNC('day',occurred_at) AS day,
   channel, COUNT(*) as events
FROM web_events
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

I have tried adding dbo before the function but I get Cannot find either column "DBO" or the user-defined function or aggregate "DBO.DATE_TRUNC", or the name is ambiguous.
and all i want is For my date column to be truncated

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Have you tried just `DATE_TRUNC`, i.e without qualifying it with DBO.

Comment: I installed sql on vs code and yes i tried using it without dbo and i  get 'DATE_TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: DATE_TRUNC is a product specific function. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: https://mysqlcode.com/alternative-to-date_trunc-in-mysql/

Comment: So sorry its mssql not mysql

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2022? This function doesn't exist on previous versions. But just `cast` `occurred_at` to `date` to remove the time portion. Also `GROUP BY 1,2` won't work

Comment: I do not why all the functions tell me they arent recognized built-in function names.

Comment: @OtimGerison why aren't you answering the question "which specific version of SQL Server are you using?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TimJarosz mssql version 1.16.0 on vs code

Comment: @OtimGerison you still haven't answered the question... which version of SQL Server are you targeting? The version you posted is the version of the code library for vscode-mssql [on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/releases). As the other commenter has stated, the function you are using doesn't work unless you're using SQL Server 2022. A search for "DATE_TRUNC" in the github repository doesn't return any results. Are you sure that VSCode library supports "DATE_TRUNC"? Have you tried "DATE_TRUNC" is SSMS instead of VSCode?

Comment: I am using version 18.12

Comment: @OtimGerison - 18.12 looks like a version that comes from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which is the client. To find the version on the server, run the query `select @@version` through SSMS on the server that you're trying to run your SQL code on.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)  Sep 24 2019 13:48:23  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )

Comment: As others have mentioned above, the DATE_TRUNC function was added in SQL 2022 while you're running on SQL 2019. As such, DATE_TRUNC isn't available to you on the version you're running. Depending on your situation, you might just be able to upgrade your instance (SQL 2022 went live a couple of weeks ago).

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith curious to know why *wouldn't* `GROUP BY 1,2` work. This is SQL Ansi standard. Of course provided that the query is correct and it does have two fields in the `select` statement to be grouped. Is it something specific to MSSQLServer? Thank you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - SQL Server only allows grouping by expressions based on input column names. This is per the SQL 92 syntax. I've no idea if a later standard has revised this as I don't have access to them. The Postgres documentation confirms the SQL 92 standard under the header ["Namespace Available to GROUP BY and ORDER BY"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) behaviour and makes reference that something changed in SQL 99 without any specifics of what,

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting. I'm not sure in which SQL Ansi this was added as well. I do know that at least Oracle, Mysql, MariaDB, PostgreSQL do accept then (I have all these on my env and tested it). I also created a fiddle with it: https://dbfiddle.uk/SD1c57U3
Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, you are using SQL Server 2019. DATE_TRUNC() isn't available to you as it is new in SQL Server 2022. If you just need the day number, use `DATEPART()` or cast to a date like this:

```
--General example.
SELECT DATEPART(day, GETDATE()) as [day];
-- Or, Just cast to a date.
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as date);

--Or specifically for the query you posted:
SELECT 
  [date]
  , channel
  , COUNT(*) as events
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , DATEPART(day, occurred_at) as [day]
        , CAST(occurred_at as date) as [date]
    FROM web_events
  ) as we
GROUP BY [date], [channel]
```

Comment: You're right. I'll update using a cast.